# dimension of $SO(2,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, solution-verification

I am looking for the dimension of the indefinite special orthogonal group $SO(2,1)$.

I computed its Lie algebra $$\mathfrak{so}(2,1)=\{M\in M_3(\Bbb R):^t\!\!MJ=-JM,\ \mathrm{Tr}(M)=0 \},$$ where $J=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &0\\
0 & 1 &0 \\
0&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}$.

Let $M=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b &c\\
d & e &f \\
g&h&i
\end{pmatrix}\in \mathfrak{so}(2,1)$.

Simple calculations using definition of $\mathfrak{so}(2,1)$ show that $a=b=d=e=i=0$, so $\dim(\mathfrak{so}(2,1))=4$.

But this doesn't make sense since $\dim(O(2,1))=3<4$.

Thank you for your help in finding my mistake.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139110/what-is-the-lie-algebra-of-the-indefinite-orthogonal-group). I obtain dimension $3$ for the Lie algebra.

Comment: Thanks @DietrichBurde, it should be $3=3(3-1)/2$ indeed the same as for $O(2,1)$. I will recheck my calculations

Comment: I forgot the transpose in my calculations :/ Many thanks for your time!
This question is solved.

Comment: @PerelMan In such cases it's better to post that edit as an answer in order to remove your question from the unanswered questions queue. (This time I did it for you.)

Comment: Thanks! Will do next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculations were wrong as I forgot the transpose. The final solution is 3 and M looks like:

$M=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & b &c\\
-b & 0 &f \\
c&f&0
\end{pmatrix}$